# Не переведена надпись include console в сниппете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, сниппеты

Собственно, по-прежнему не переведена надпись <kbd>include console</kbd>.

PS: Решил всё-таки завести тему на мете, чтобы было позаметнее :)

Comment: @Nicolas а почему завершено? в сниппете все еще не переведено

Comment: @Grundy Новый перевод появится на сайте после развёртки следующей сборки. Обычно, это новые сборки появляются по несколько раз в день.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, аааа. просто я сейчас проверял, был еще английский текст

Comment: @Grundy Скорее всего, строка обновится к вечеру завтрашнего дня.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, это типа выходные сейчас идут?:)

Comment: Если честно, не знаю. Лишь предполагаю, что завтра вечером строки обновятся.